# OpAmp Based Linear Regulators

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I was going through this :
http://tangentsoft.net/elec/opamp-linreg.html

Vis-a-vis **Jung 2000 Regulator**:
[image]

I had a few doubts, maybe someone could clarify :

1) What is the idea of putting the green LED D1 in the base circuit of Q2 ?

2) Can we use any NPN in place of [D44H11](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/4213.pdf) with an equivalent current rating ?

3) Can we use any FET OpAmp in place of [AD825](http://www.westfloridacomponents.com/mm5/graphics/ds/ad825.pdf) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an attempt to build a very low noise output voltage regulator. It tends to be used by people who favor oxygen-free-copper speaker cables with specific wire layup patterns, and the like. That's not to say that it does not have improved performance, but that in most cases it will be used or needed only by people who can hear and sense things in music that mere mortals are ever barred from hearing. Reading the whole article is worthwhile if you are interested in what they are trying to achieve.

The green LED acts as a voltage reference for a constant current source formed by Q2 R5 D1 R4. A number of silicon diodes could perhaps have been used instead of the LED. Say that V_green_LED  is 3V. This puts Q2 base 3V below the LED Anode so Q2 emitter is 3.0-Vb3 = 3 - 0.6 = 2.4V below the D1 Anode. This 2.4V appears across R5 and causes I = V/R = 2.4/249 ~= 10 mA to flow in R5 and Q2. This current is available to Q1 as base drive and the error amplifier U1 controls Q1 by "sucking out" whatever part of this current is required to maintain regulation.

The people who have designed this circuit specified  Q1 as a D44H11 [datasheet here](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MJ/MJD44H11.pdf) because it made total sense to them to do so. I'd say that it was just a reasonably capable DPAk NPN power transistor and that a dozens of alternatives would be OK - but the audiophiles would probably assure you that they could hear the difference if you changed to something else. I certainly couldn't - but my hearing is not audiophile class.

If I was designing this circuit I'd probably have made Q1 a PNP (or P Channel MOSFET) because it is far easier to provide it with heavy forward bias when required under any conditions and the dropout voltage would be very much superior. I have little doubt that the somewhat awkward  NPN arrangement was used because it conveyed some great advantage in the estimate of the designer.

Similarly, the AD825 op amp [datasheet here](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/Data_Sheets/AD825.pdf) has been chosen with great care. This is a more understandable choice. This is a $5 opamp and has reasonably impressive performance.  125 V/uS slew (!), 41 MHz 3dB bandwidth, input bias current of 20 pA and noise current of 10 fA/√Hz 
Input voltage noise of 12 nV/√Hz. In practice you could use a far lower spec opamp there - and may not hear the difference. Depending on your ears.

If you care enough to build this circuit then leaving the opamp as specified is probably wise. Changing Q1 MAY be OK.

Note that even the choice of reference - here D5, is based on low noise considerations. The [LM329- datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm329.pdf) is NOT a bandgap reference - it is a buried zener diode of special design.

Comment: After watching some videos from "eevblog" on linear PSUs ,I believe PNP based LDOs are difficult to stabilize,so maybe that's the reason for using a NPN ?

Answer (score 5):

> What is the idea of putting the green LED D1 in the base circuit of Q2 ?

D1, R4, R5 and Q2 form a constant current source by forcing a constant voltage (D1 Vf - Q2 Vbe) across a fixed resistance (R5). R4 is just there to limit the current through the LED. You can use 2 or 3 diodes in series here in place of the LED, or a zener, but they'll likely be less accurate or noisier.

This current pushes the op-amp's output deep into class A, so that instead of regulating the output voltage by pushing a varying current into the Q1 base, it can only pull current away from the CCS, thereby affecting how much goes into Q1's base.

This keeps the op-amp's output transistor away from the crossover distortion area except at extreme output load. Without that constant load, you'd get crossover distortion at low power supply current demands. It's more common in audio circuits to have a highly variable supply current range that includes low current values than one that constantly stays up near the output current limit of the power supply, so we design around that by trading away excellent performance at a limit we hope never to get near to gain excellent performance with a variable load.

It also has the nice side effect of making the regulator inherently current-limited: the regulator's maximum output current is the current source's value times Q1's hFE. The hFE varies quite widely, so this is not an accurate way to limit the output current unless you adjust the current source to match, but in power supplies that regulate by having the op-amp push current into Q1's base, the output current limit is typically much higher, since you set the current source value much lower than the output current limit of the op-amp. If you set the limit appropriately to your load circuit's demands, it could potentially save the power supply or load circuit from destruction in case of a short circuit.

The article you reference shows several other circuit designs that operate the other way, for comparison.

> Can we use any NPN in place of D44H11 with an equivalent current rating ?

Yes.

That transistor was chosen because of its linearity over the current ranges the power supply was designed for.

Perhaps there is a better transistor for your particular application. Maybe you don't need as much output current, so you might choose a smaller transistor. You would select the transistor to put the expected power supply load current right in the middle of the most linear part of the transistor's transfer function.

If instead your interest is in switching to some generic transistor type, just beware that this may increase the amount of distortion the op-amp must counteract. Since op-amps are not perfect, this will show up as slightly worse performance at the power supply output.

> Can we use any FET OpAmp in place of AD825 ?

There is some flexibility here, but there are many chips that won't work.

The first thing you have to do is look to stability. Some chips are prone to oscillation in this circuit. This is largely due to the fact that this circuit's feedback loop is physically larger than is common for op-amp circuits. This is especially true if you use the remote sensing feature, not shown in that schematic but detailed nicely in the original article by Walt Jung.

Beyond that, you also want a chip with low noise, the ability to sink enough current to drive the pass transistor accurately, the ability to start up reliably in the face of power cycling, a high amount of feedback over the required regulation bandwidth, etc. Many chips will fail one or more of these requirements.

You don't actually have to use a FET-input chip. The circuit doesn't try to balance input offset currents, but they'd just show up as a variance in the power supply output voltage, which is easily dealt with by making R1 or R2 adjustable.

Comment: It is such a great thing that site owner answers the question :)

Comment: Which owner are you referring to? I don't see anyone from StackExchange in this thread...

Comment: @Warren Young -  I noticed that Warren was quoting text from the article as if it was his own words. So I had another look, and lo!, they are his own words :-) - he wrote the page being discussed :-). Well done.

Comment: @Madmanguruman - the page that the circuit diagram and description comes from was written BY Warren Young, who also provided this answer.

Comment: Thanks so much gentlemen.
I am making an instrument for some electrochemical application (still in the ideating stage).
http://bank-ic.de/en/aplicat/hifi.html,.
Being from a non electronic background,its great to get such quality advice from the experts.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I misunderstood, obviously. My bad.

Comment: EmbSysDev emailed me asking me to comment here.

Comment: I would like to mark both the replies as right/useful,but the site does not allow me to.Maybe instead of "correct",it should be phrased as "useful" and allow multiple replies to be selected.